# Planning for commercial display technology in 5-10 year timeframe?

Tags: display

I'm involved with a project to plan for equipment over a 5-10 year period.  One daunting issue is display technology.  I'm being pressed for a decision but am unsure.  So the question is: What display technology would you be proposing that would exist over a 5-10 year horizon?

Comment: What's the context? Do you want PC monitors for user desktops, or a Jumbotron for a football stadium?

Comment: Planning for PC monitor and workstation type of situation.

Comment: 4K monitors are relatively new, and 8K are just starting to hit the market. You may require a discrete video card to drive these monitors. -- Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Probably closer to a mass kiosk situation...i.e. designed complex application running on pcs.

Comment: Right. The more specific you can be, the more relevant the answers. As it stands, the question is pretty vague.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect progressions towards (semi)transparent displays with integrated 3dmotion detection so that people can interface with it like in Minority Report.

Comment: I'm not seeing this type of technology in widespread use or at a cost point that would allow it for general use.  Nice thought however.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning for purshasing; a lot of option exist.

I take your comment about kiosk. Did you thought to a solution like vmware horizon/view or xendesktop ?

You purshase only terminal & monitor (and some terminal are builtin in the monitor already)

The beauty of such solution is that if the terminal broke, the user can just replug's one on the network, and the config of where it connect can be all ajusted by DHCP.

Another beauty of such solution is that you can use some model that support to connect to the app only (remoteapp or xenapp), thus the user no longer need a "desktop". I did that for some secretary, I published for them Internet Explorer too, and the need for the desktop license, antivirus license, etc.. was all gone.

I'am more used to xendesktop, but what I love in xendesktop (and view offer that) is that you can make a pool of desktop (with using roaming profile). Thus if the user got a problem, he restart is computer and fallback to another freshly restarted computer. That way X computer never change, unless you make the update in it, and you are sure everyone start the day the same, perfect for kiosk's mode.

Comment: Unfortunately the actual application is very complex and requires a lot of cpu and parts.    This application will be a localized network of computers.

Comment: @mdpc If the software you install is complex, what their bestpractice told about scalling ? and does they offer pre sales services ? (I ask, as some software have special need that only the vendor can address. An example, hospital's urgency monitor for RX, to allow the doctor to make a diagnostic you need 10k resolution monitor with special width)